# Should undiscussed burninates be approved? (fortify360 in this case)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits, burninate-system

I've just [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6077661) a suggested edit removing the [fortify360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortify360) tag.
I didn't know Fortify but looking at the tag wiki it looked like Fortify 360 didn't exist any more and the question didn't mention it explicitly, so I assumed removing the tag was correct.

The next suggested edit in the queue was about the same tag removal, on a question way older than the last one, perhaps from a time where this software still existed.
I was unsure and skipped, and the next item was, again, a removal of that tag.
[Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399723/douglas-held) seems to go through all those questions with that tag and remove them.

I looked for a burninate-request but couldn't find one. How to deal with that?
Should that tag be burninated?

Should I reject such edits and expect a link to a burninate-request in the edit comment?
Or should I just skip and leave it for reviewers knowing more about Fortify?

Comment: I left a comment on one of the approved question edits

Comment: I can imagine that the fortify360 history gets mentioned on the fortify-software tag wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not the proper procedure.  Douglas should have simply asked for somebody to create a synonym, using a meta post.

The biggest problem with these retags is the DOS attack on other SO users' front pages.  The SE engine just doesn't deal with them well enough, thinking that the questions need to be reactivated.  My own front page showed a bunch of these old Fortify questions this morning, there was absolutely no point in me looking at them again for just a retag.  And of course crowding out questions that *should* get my attention.  Somebody ought to review retags, there's just no point in *everybody* having to do this.

Comment: Removing tags individually is currently the only viable way to burninate a tag.  Though you're right; this should have been a synonym.

Answer (score 6):

I have worked for Fortify for almost 8 years. For a short while we renamed our product suite Fortify 360.  This name has been defunct since at least 2011 now; but it has become a Stack Overflow tag almost as popular as "fortify" and "fortify-software".  All three of these tags are logically equivalent and it drives me nuts.

I do not have enough reputation to suggest a tag synonym to clear these up. (although if it carries any weight, I am a top contributor on 2 of the 3 tags)

In my spare time, sometimes I query for the fortify360 tag and delete it. 80% of the time it is already in conjunction with "fortify" and "fortify-software".

Comment: Synonyms sounds like the right thing to do. Pretty much requires a moderator on low-volume tags. For next time: you could have asked a question here on meta to get that done. (Hopefully a mod will read your answer and make that change.)

Comment: Please also fix the tags' wiki and excerpt so that they are neutral and descriptive.  Right now they read like advertisements, make unsupported claims, and use the first person.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have created the meta request here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275314/burninate-request-for-tag-fortify360

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And that you're a top contributor in these tags would have been something else I could have looked for to see that _what_ you're doing was probably correct, the question being only _how_ to do that, and I could have left a comment under the first question as Rene did.