# Burninate request for tag: fortify360

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, burninate-request, synonym-request

I have worked for Fortify for almost eight years. For a short while we renamed our product suite Fortify 360. This name has been defunct since at least 2011 now; but it has become a Stack Overflow tag almost as popular as "fortify" and "fortify-software". All three of these tags are logically equivalent and it drives me nuts.

I do not have enough reputation to suggest a tag synonym to clear these up. (Although if it carries any weight, I am a top contributor on 2 of the 3 tags.)

In my spare time, sometimes I query for the fortify360 tag and delete it. 80% of the time it is already in conjunction with "fortify" and "fortify-software".

My request, specifically:

- Keep [fortify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortify)
- Re-tag [fortify360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortify360)
- Synonymize [fortify-software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortify-software)

Meta-question leading to this request: [Should undiscussed burninates be approved? (fortify360 in this case)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275309)

Comment: Reference: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275309/should-undiscussed-burninates-be-approved-fortify360-in-this-case/275312

Comment: You do not need full editing privileges to take part in a tag burnination. Please see [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250933/3622940) I were the reviewer earlier who rejected your edits for removing the tag without fixing every other problem within the post.

Comment: @Unihedron: Oh god why would you reject a useful and helpful edit just because it didn't fix "_every other problem_" within the post???? That's a horrendous way to review edits.

Comment: PLEASE rewrite the [tag:fortify] wiki and excerpt to conform to wiki guidelines of being neutral and informative.  Right now both are spam, not information.  They use first-person, make unsubstantiated claims, and generally read like advertisements.